# ¿Cómo cambiar un valor en cuadro de opciones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un leech premium que al cargar los archivos da la opción de zipiarlos y partirlos, descubrí que tal opciones es sugerida y que modificando los valores establecidos (por ej: `value="10485760">10240 Mo<`) puedo poner el tamaño que crea mas conveniente. 
Entonces la idea es hacer un `script` para `Tampermonkey` que modifique esos valores.

El `HTML`en cuestion es:

```
<select name="archive-max-size">
    <option value="10485760">10240 Mo</option>
    <option value="5242880">5120 Mo</option>
    <option value="4194304">4096 Mo</option>
    <option value="3145728">3072 Mo</option>
    <option value="2097152">2048 Mo</option>
    <option value="1048576">1024 Mo</option>
    <option value="524288">512 Mo</option>
    <option value="262144">256 Mo</option>
    <option value="204800">200 Mo</option>
    <option value="102400">100 Mo</option>
</select>
```

La idea es cambiar `value="10485760">10240 Mo<` a otros a conveniencia por ej: `value="15485760">15 GB<` también hacer algo similar con el resto.

Pude hacerlo así:
`{document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('value="10485760">10240 Mo<', 'value="15485760">15 GB<');}` funciona, pero al ejecutarse ese `Script` daña el formulario (no se muy bien como explicarlo) por ej si tengo un archivo listo para subir, cuando se ejecuta el `script` el archivo ya no aparece "a la espera" para subir y la opción de cargar archivo desde la PC deja de funcionar. Supongo que con `JQuery` el cambio no influiría mas allá de lo esperado.

La verdad no tengo un `Script`echo para esto, es por eso que les pido su ayuda, dejo un ejemplo "live" donde se puede probar con un ejemplo que amablemente me pasó [Einer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/38468/einer):

https://jsfiddle.net/qwertyip/xjnk3voq/2/

Comment: Tendrías que poner un ejemplo que sea reproducible para ver tu error y poder darte una solución mejor a tu problema. ¿A que te refieres con **termina no funcionando el resto del sitio X**?

Comment: Hola, ahí actualicé -y me gustaría pensar- aclaré eso que preguntas, gracias por pasar y la recomendación.

Answer (score 1):

Solo tendrias que recorrer cada `option` del `select` con el metodo `.each()`. Para asignarle el valor al option se utilizar la funcion `.val()` y para asignar el texto `.text()`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function modificar()
{
  var data = [{val: "15485760", text: "15 GB"},{val: "otros valores", text: "otros valores"},{val: "otros valores", text: "otros valores 2"}];
  $("select[name='archive-max-size'] option").each(function(index, element){
  
    $(element).val(data[index].val)
    .text(data[index].text);
  
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="archive-max-size">
<option value="10485760">10240 Mo</option>
<option value="5242880">5120 Mo</option>
<option value="4194304">4096 Mo</option>
</select>

<button onclick="modificar()">Button</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ¿como aplicaría ese ejemplo? perdón pero la verdad es que soy un aficionado en esto